# Why in building telegram4android in android studio returns errors cannot find symbol method sqrt(float)?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, symbols, telegram

After i fixed problems gradle,and gradle synced correctly.now i want to to build apk for telegram,it returns:

> Error:(372, 34) error: cannot find symbol method sqrt(float)
>   Error:(389, 35) error: cannot find symbol method sqrt(int)

i want to build for API 23.i used android studi1.5.1 too.my friend please help me to solve building apk for telegram4android.

- complete errors:

  > Information:Gradle tasks [:TMessagesProj:assembleDebug]
  >   :TMessagesProj:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:checkDebugManifest
  >   :TMessagesProj:preFossBuild UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42210Library UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices3265Library UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:prepareDebugDependencies
  >   :TMessagesProj:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
  >   :TMessagesProj:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
  >   C:\Users\root\Documents\Android\Telegram-dev\TMessagesProj\src\main\java\org\telegram\ui\Components\Scroller.java
  >   Error:(372, 34) error: cannot find symbol method sqrt(float)
  >   Error:(389, 35) error: cannot find symbol method sqrt(int)
  >   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  >   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  >   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
  >   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  >   Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  >   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  >   Information:BUILD FAILED
  >   Information:Total time: 25 mins 36.812 secs
  >   Information:3 errors
  >   Information:0 warnings
  >   Information:See complete output in console

can any help me.i mentioned i searched but it is n't solution for telegram.wiki and issue project on github is disabled.
in github is talked that it was built successfully in android studio.

in advance thanks

Comment: even i asked on codeproject but no one didn't answered.

Comment: i have doubt the source telegram have errors.i think configuration has problem

Comment: Yes , i think sqrt(float) function is depreciated. replace it with sqrt(int) may it works

Comment: i will test and i will post result here

Comment: yes,you are right.i chagen build this to api 19  thanks very mcuh,it has another error but it is not this:)

Comment: Thanks i posted it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqrt(float) function is depreciated. replace it with sqrt(int) may it helps you.